# Running command had status 1

Tags: r

I've tried to run command in R 2.15.2

```
rsaga.geoprocessor(lib="ta_channels", module=0, param=list(ELEVATION="DEMflt.sgrd", CHNLNTWRK=paste("channels", i, ".sgrd", sep=""), CHNLROUTE="channel_route.sgrd", SHAPES="channels.shp", INIT_GRID="DEMflt.sgrd", DIV_CELLS=3, MINLEN=40), show.output.on.console=FALSE)
```

and I'm constantly getting this warning:

```
    Warning message:
running command '"C:/Users/Nenad/Documents/R/win-library/2.15/RSAGA/SAGA-GIS/saga_cmd.exe" ta_preprocessor 2 -DEM "DEM1.sgrd" -RESULT "DEMflt.sgrd" -MINSLOPE "0.05"' had status 1
```

I use windows 8 and also tried to ran R as admin.

Any idea what is the problem? Thanks!

Comment: You could open a command console (somewhere in Start/Programs/Accessories if I remember correctly) and run the command directly. Maybe it will have more information about what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Idk how actual it is, but I've been struggling with "***had status 1***" warning a lot. Especially it got really annoying when I tried to use `seasonal` package to conduct the `X13-ARIMA-SEATS` seasonal decomposition of time series. The `seasonal::seas` command just didn't work, because in the code of this command there is a stop condition when running a certain stuff with cmd.exe returns non-zero status. While, as it was mentioned before, '***status 1***' doesn't prevent command execution, in case of `seasonal` package it does.

The problem in my case was caused by some mistake in Windows Registry (Win 10), that in turn caused warning `System cannot find the path specified` when launching CMD.exe or PowerShell, which caused warning inside `R` as well. So to fix it:

1. Press `Win+R` -> regedit
2. In `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor` folder clean the value of *Autorun* record (it should be empty)
3. Do the same for *Autorun* in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor`

After these actions annoying warning with "***has status 1***" has gone and seasonal::seas started to work perfectly.
Hope it will be usefull for somebody.

Answer (score 0):

Running `system` commands from `R` can be really tricky. In my experience, as long as the exit code is not `127` then the command did run, and you could use the `intern=TRUE` switch in the `system` command for a more verbose output. If you run the command again, the warning message could contain a `errmsg` attribute as well for some more info. hth